# Unable to start the system after plugging a formatted ext4 4TB USB3 disk drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04 with only a snap of NextCloud installed.

I have added today a 4TB Hard Disk, I've created a unique partition with gdisk with  a GPT partition table and then formatted using ext4.

Then I've restarted the system and I get the following screen message:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type journalctl -xb to view
system logs, ....
```

In the journal I don't see any error.

Instead in the startup I see that the system has problem mounting the drives.

- sda(ext4) is the main sata drive, with the OS, and mount fine
- sdb(ext4) is the new secondary 4TB USB drive, that started all the issue.
- sdc(ext3) is the old secondary 2TB USB drive, that I have to replace
  with the new one 4TB drive. *Please note that before this drive was on sdb.*

I've modified the fstab file in order to mount the drives at boot accordingly to their filesystem.

If I run fdisk the two drives are not shown

sdb (the new 4TB USB drive) is mounted, and I can list a sample file I've placed inside.

sdc (the old 2TB USB drive) doesn't mount as it says:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Please note that if I remove the new 4TB USB drive, leaving the old 2TB USB drive, everything works perfectly.

The issue is present only when I try to plug the new 4TB USB drive even alone without the old 2TB USB drive.

**fstab**:

```
UUID=bb09e344-df6c-11e8-98f5-b8aeed773314 / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=31EF-3A33 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0
/dev/sdb /media/sdb ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/sdc /media/sdc ext3 defaults 0 2
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: Without seeing the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -f` it's impossible to diagnose this.

Comment: @mook765 trying to solve the issue I've messed up the MBR/GPT of the old drive and I've lost it. So I decided to reinstall everything from scratch as I had no data in them. thanks

Comment: You should not use device names like `/dev/sdb` in fstab, also `dev/sdb` is not a partition but the whole drive. Use UUID like in the first lines to identify the correct partition. That's what `lsblk -f` is for. Your question seems to be obsolete now.